# Write a recursive script to move all files one folder up

Tags: linux, shell-script, directory-structure

I know that there are multiple questions already asked of this type. Still, some of them still remain unanswered while, the others don't answer my query.

Consider the following directory hierarchy:

A directory, say `f1` contains multiple directories.
I want to write a script to move all files in all directories and their sub-directories, to respective parent directories except for the directory `f1`

Now Consider an example:

A directory f1 contains files file1,file2,file3,...,filen
and sub-directories sd1,sd2,sd3,...,sdn, which in turn contains sub-directories again!!.

each sub-directory in turn contains files having same name as that of the parent directory, i.e. file1,file2... . However, all files have different content.
After the operation, all files in these sub-directories should move to there parent directories. I don't think name collision should be an issue, as all files will have different 'path-names' in the end. If only name collision can occur, it is in the root directory, as files cannot move to root's parent directory. There, the word `root` should be appended to the originally existing file.

some example paths:

```
f1/sd1/sd1/file1
f1/sd1/file1
f1/file1
```

after operation,

```
f1/sd1/sd1/file1 -> f1/sd1/file
f1/sd1/file1     -> f1/file1
f1/file1         ->f1/file1_root
```

Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be a script? `mv f1/* .` should do what you need (assuming you're one directory up from `f1`).

Comment: will you please explain me the working? I mean, `f1/* .` will move all contents in f1 directory to current directory. But, will this work recursively?

Comment: You'd better show a larger example with how `f1/file` and `f1/dir/file` and `f1/dir/dir/file` and what the outcome should look like.  It's unclear how this should look afterwards, and how name collisions should be handled.

Comment: Any question like "Write a script ..." should include what you tried and where you're stuck. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: some examples were like mv -R ./* ../* But it didn't quite go the way I expected it too, and as I forgot about the # I was in, I had an annoying reinstall. Then I tried something like for((i=0;i<600;i++)) mv ./* ../*;cd ..Then I understood, it worked the other way round. It should work from the parent directory instead of from the child directory

Comment: You'd have to first rename directories to avoid clashes between directories and files. And you have to think what to do with `f1/somefile` and `f2/somefile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move every file one up using `find` and `-execdir`:

```
find f1 -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir mv -t ../ {} +
```

> Beware, that this will overwrite duplicate filenames, consider using `mv -b` to backup existing files.

- `-mindepth 2` will exclude the lowest level folder (`f1`).
- `-execdir ... +` will run the command in the folder of the found files.

Comment: Will you please see the edited question on how to resolve duplicate filenames?

Comment: And, this isn't necessarily for depth=2, It can even be till when directory doesn't have a sub-directory!!!

Comment: ?? It's not `depth 2` but `mindepth 2`, `find` is recursive by default.

Comment: Oh sorry!! I should have been a bit more clear

Comment: Will you suggest a better strategy to resolve duplicates?

Comment: Sorry, guess I put this question on the wrong site. I have now posted it to codegolf. Thanks a lot for your time and effort